# Why does matrix multiplication give different results depending on how they are grouped?

Tags: numpy, matrix

We know that `A*B*C = A*(B*C)`, but why this matrix multiplication got different result?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

B = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

print( A.dot( np.linalg.inv(B) ).dot(A.T) )

print( A.dot( np.linalg.inv(B).dot(A.T) ) )
```

The result is

```
[[ 0.5  2. ]
 [ 1.   4. ]]
```

and

```
[[  2.   4.]
 [  8.  16.]]
```

Answer (score 3):

`B` is of insufficient rank to take an inverse.  To get at least consistent results, use `np.linalg.pinv` for the pseudo inverse.

```
np.linalg.matrix_rank(B)
# we want 3

# we got 2
2
```

---

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

B = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

print( A.dot( np.linalg.pinv(B) ).dot(A.T) )

print( A.dot( np.linalg.pinv(B).dot(A.T) ) )

[[ 1.  4.]
 [ 2.  5.]]
[[ 1.  4.]
 [ 2.  5.]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Floating point arithmetical operations are **not associative**. Usually we don't notice this because the numerical differences between matrices `A*(B*C)` and `(A*B)*C` are tiny. But in this case, you are trying to invert a non-invertible matrix B, which Numpy actually tries to do, getting some absurd result:

```
[[  3.15251974e+15  -6.30503948e+15   3.15251974e+15]
 [ -6.30503948e+15   1.26100790e+16  -6.30503948e+15]
 [  3.15251974e+15  -6.30503948e+15   3.15251974e+15]]
```

The magnitude of these numbers is such that errors of size ~1 are to be expected at the double precision level (you get about 16 accurate digits). The multiplication by A and A.T brings the matrix entires back to something small, due to a lot of cancellation. But when very large numbers cancel each other, the relative error grows; and the result ends up being fairly meaningless.

Comment: Very well said!